# How to set the Debugging info to True from command line

Tags: sass

i am new to Sass and i want to use Firebug extension Firesass for debugging. 
i read somewhere that i have to set the debugging info to true before using Firesass.
can you help me like from my command prompt how to enable the debugging info to true.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sass --debug-info
```

or

```
compass --debug-info
```